# # of sets in direct mapped cache

Tags: caching

If I have 9 address bits, how many sets are there in a direct mapped cache?
If I have 10 address bits, how many sets are there in a direct mapped cache?

Is there a general formula for this question?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For direct mapped, each address only maps to one location in the cache, thus the number of sets in a direct mapped cache is just the size of the cache.

There would be 0 bits for the tag, and you don't provide enough information to determine the index or displacement bits.

Assuming you are using word addressing and you meant there are 9 or 10 bits for the index + tag:

9 bits -> 2^9 sets

10 bits -> 2^10 sets

Comment: Ok, how can I separate the tag, index, and byte offset?

Comment: How big are the words, and how big is the cache?

Comment: I think that is the problem I am having, none of that was specified.

Comment: Well how big is the memory? If the memory is > 1024 words, you can probably assume that there are 1024 words in the cache, and thus 1024 sets.

Comment: 1024 words for cache isn't big and thus sounds about right -- thats only 4KB if the words are 32-bit

Comment: Or if its only 1KB of cache and each word is 32-bit, that means there are 2 bits for byte offset, so there would be 2^8 sets

Comment: So assuming 2^10 for size of memory = 1024 which also = 1024 sets.

Comment: Assuming 1024 for size, bits 0-1 are byte offset, bits 2-4 are index, and bits 5-9 are tag?

Comment: If you only know the size of memory, you can't answer the question. 2^10 is probably the size of the cache. If you are addressing bytes, and the machine is using 32-bit words, there are 256 sets. But if you are addressing words, there are 1024 sets.

Comment: Sorry -- I got tag and index in reverse above =)

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of the question, I am not sure what I can and cannot assume. The figure the question references refer to 10 bit addresses

Comment: OK so 2 bits byte offset means 32-bit words, 3 bit index means there are 2^3 (8) sets

Comment: And I believe the memory size is 256 words. (1KB)

Answer (score 0):

OK, for (a), draw yourself 8 columns to start off with -- those will be your sets in the cache.

For each address, check if the address (only high bits -- ignore lowest two bits) is at the bottom of the column numbered by bits 2-4. If there is nothing written in that column, or the bits 2-10 don't match, its a miss. If bits 2-10 match what you currently have written at bottom of that column -- its a hit because you have that address in cache. Regardless of whether it is a hit or miss, cross out current value in the column, and write the new address there.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The number of blocks will be equal to 1 in case of a direct map.

Now you can get the number of sets by (Size of cache)/(No. of blocks)

which here is (size of cache)/1 = size of cache.